# Hosts doesn't work

Tags: networking, data-connection, supersu, hosts

So i play a game that uses a server to detect emulator users.

Is there anyway to prevent other emulator users from being in my online game ?

The problem is that other emulator users usually use hacks and cheats on their device's, and I do not want to be in a game with those players.

I already tried adding the server block using hosts and i have root access on my emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do it, however you'll need to NOT be using an emulator to connect.

The main problem is that you are using this server to connect yourself and your own emulator... The server is detecting that you should be playing a game with equally matched players and therefore other emulator users.

If you did Block the server from connecting, I'm sure you would also be blocking yourself.

To get around this, you would need to mock a device that is not an emulator, Maybe your UA ( User Agent ) is saying your an emulator, so you'd need to Mock a device that is Not an emulator

"in hope that the server only checks your UA String"

It could be also using the Application to identify your device even further, Therefore you need to change your device inside the build.prop to mock a Non-Emulator device, some device's will also use CPU and hardware inspection to identify the proper capabilities.

It is very hard to Trick some apps, and others are simple !

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try what you suggested but blocking emulator detection server worked before in previous version but after the last update i can't block tge server i used vpn and hosts to block it but the server appears in a different ip with the same domain if there is a way to block such server it would be a lot easier.  Is there?

Comment: I also tried blocking all connection from that server port with iptables but still somehow data was sent to the server and i still got detected even though my moniter showed no connection from that port

Comment: The thing is i don't mind playing with emulator in fact i only can play in emulator since i'm more used to computer not phone. But about %80 of emulator players use hacks and ruin the game experience for me so i'm trying to avoid playing with them